# matplotlib grouped bars in a bar graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm playing with matplotlib and pandas to create a bar graph.
I have a dataframe of world cup teams and here is what `df.head()` shows
[image]

I want to create a bar graph, where each bar is a unique `team`, and each team in a `group` are graphed close together, with unique groups between a noticeable distance apart.
Here is what I currently have:

```
caps_per_team_per_group = df.groupby(['group', 'team']).Caps.sum()
caps_per_team_per_group.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15,5))
```

[image]

and for visual purposes, I want it to look like this: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is to reset the index of your groupby data frame and use seaborn's factorplot.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# Setting up
group_A = ['Egypt', 'Russia', 'Uruguay', 'Saudi Arabia']
group_B = ['Spain', 'Portugal', 'Iran', 'Morocco']
group_C = ['France', 'Denmark', 'Australia', 'Peru']
team = group_A + group_B + group_C
group =['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
caps = np.random.randint(5, 50, 12)
caps_per_team_per_group = pd.DataFrame({ 'Caps': caps}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(group, team)), names=['Group', 'Team']))

# Reset index and plot
caps_per_team_per_group.reset_index(inplace=True)
g = sns.factorplot(x="Group", y="Caps", hue='Team', data=caps_per_team_per_group, kind="bar", palette="muted")

n [47]: caps_per_team_per_group
Out[47]: 
                    Caps
Group Team              
A     Egypt           43
      Russia          39
      Uruguay         20
      Saudi Arabia    49
B     Spain            6
      Portugal         8
      Iran            32
      Morocco         11
C     France          14
      Denmark         41
      Australia       29
      Peru             8
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the detail and effort you put into your answer, thank you.

Comment: You are very are welcome. I would recommend posting the table data in a text format and with more representative contents (e.g. more than one team and group) in future posts.